# Adding Google play services to binding library on Xamarin

Tags: android, xamarin, xamarin.android, google-play-services, xamarin-studio

I have a java .jar library that I want to add to my Xamarin app. The problem is that it uses APIs from the google play services library for ads.

I've added the the Xamarin.GooglePlayServices.ads and base to my app's packages and this did not work. 
I've tried adding the Google Play Services to the Binding Library itself this also did not work.

Any ideas here?

Thanks

Comment: "Did not work" isn't a very good description.